# VBA Excel - Open IE window to URL, pause, then close

Tags: vba, internet-explorer

I am limited to using VBA to accomplish this. The goal is to programmatically Open a new IE window which is a duplicate of a window already open. 
I need to display this window for limited amount of time (in this example I am waiting 15 seconds), then I want to close one of the two IE windows I have open. 
I have cobbled together code fragments from a few examples I have found and this is partially working, but the results are not as I would expect.

- First I am able to find the IE instances but even though I think I have coded an exit, both windows are closed.
- The MsgBox I am using for debugging never appears.
- With each run of the code the error message below appears

[image]

Below is the code I am trying to get to work, but failing with.

```
Private Sub OpenReport()
Dim IE
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate "http://~~~~~~~~~.net/reports/views/result/reportResult.faces"
' Wait for a period of time contained in TimeValue
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:15"))
' Now close ONE of the IE windows (Currently closing all of them)
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_Process")
' Find IE Instances
For Each objItem In colItems
    If objItem.Name = "iexplore.exe" Then
        On Error Resume Next
        objItem.Terminate ' Terminates all instead of exiting after finding one IE window
        MsgBox objItem.Name & " " & objItem.ProcessID & " " & objItem.CommandLine 'Doesn't appear
        Exit For
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: because you are terminating by the processname. That's not unique. Use processid to kill.

Comment: `MsgBox objItem.Name & " " & objItem.ProcessID & " " & objItem.CommandLine 'Doesn't appear` actually appears, exactly as shown at the screenshot, and that isn't an error message.

Comment: Why do you use WMI and `.Terminate` to close IE window? You may just use `IE.Quit`.

Comment: Omegastripes - I need to terminate only one of the two windows. Need the other to remain open.  Cyboarhu - I'll see about idenifying the processid and kill it. Tx both.

Comment: @KenCarter `IE.Quit` closes only one of the two windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appreciate the input but had to go a slightly different route to get this working as it should...

The key to getting one instance of IE to close was solved by using TaskKill (commandline WScript).

Below is the full solution

```
Private Sub OpenReport()
Dim IE
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate "http://~~~~~~~~~~~net/reports/views/result/reportResult.faces"
' Wait for a period of time contained in TimeValue
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:15"))
' Now close ONE of the IE windows (Currently closing all of them)
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_Process")
' Find an IE instance
For Each objitem In colItems
    If objitem.Name = "iexplore.exe" Then
        On Error Resume Next

        Shell ("TaskKill /PID " & objitem.ProcessID)

    Exit For
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution for this issue. I suggest you to try to mark your own answer as an accepted answer for this question after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @Zhi - Yep... was planning to do exactly that... thanks!